# JpaRepository, how do you query against a OneToMany unidirectional field?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-onetomany

I have an entity User and an Entity AccessGroup.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;
.....
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable
        (
                name="USER_ACCESS_GROUPS",
                joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_ID") },
                inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="ACCESS_GROUP_ID") }
        )
    private Set<AccessGroup> accessGroups;
.....
}
```

My AccessGroup Entity I don't want any relations defined, as it will be used in many other places with other associations.

```
@Entity
public class AccessGroup {
.....
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ACCESS_GROUP_ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "GROUP_NAME")
    private String groupName;
.....
}
```

What I want to be able to do is now query a Set of users that are in a particular group or multiple groups. I tried using in my Repository this:

```
Set<User> findAllByAccessGroupsIn(Set<AccessGroup> accessGroups);
```

but this results in a unique index or primary key violation. I have a lack of understanding here, I am not quite sure why we are trying to perform an insert on a SELECT operation?

I also tried a Named Query, but it results in the same issue.

my test looks like:

```
@Test
public void testQueries() {
    assertEquals(10, userRepository.count());
    assertEquals(10, accessGroupRepository.count());

    final Set<AccessGroup> groupSet = new HashSet<>();
    groupSet.addAll(accessGroupRepository.findAll().subList(0, 2));

    final Set<User> usersInTheseParticularGroups = userRepository.findAllByAccessGroupsIn(groupSet); //FAILS WITH ERROR

}
```

In this test I expect 2 users to come back, user 1 has all groups, and user 2 has only one group that is in the set.

EDIT: Adding Stack

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint["UK_OMDFVD0I0TQVKFXALPUDUIMXN_INDEX_A ON PUBLIC.USER_ACCESS_GROUPS(ACCESS_GROUP_ID) VALUES (6, 7)"; SQL statement:
insert into user_access_groups user_id, access_group_id) values (?, ?) [23505-192]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy193.findByAccessGroupsIn(Unknown Source)
at com.user.domain.repository.Users.UserRepositoryTest.shouldTestQueries(UserRepositoryTest.java:139)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1319)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1251)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1319)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:102)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:92)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 38 moreCaused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_OMDFVD0I0TQVKFXALPUDUIMXN_INDEX_A ON
PUBLIC.USER_ACCESS_GROUPS(ACCESS_GROUP_ID) VALUES (6, 7)"; SQL statement:
insert into user_access_groups user_id, access_group_id) values (?, ?) [23505-192]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.getDuplicateKeyException(BaseIndex.java:103)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.checkUnique(MVSecondaryIndex.java:231)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVSecondaryIndex.add(MVSecondaryIndex.java:190)
at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTable.addRow(MVTable.java:704)
at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:156)
at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:98)
at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:258)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:160)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:146)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
... 65 more
```

EDIT 2: 
I found that the EntityManager seems to be hanging onto some inserts before my test, likeley from my @Before block where I initialize the DB with some entities. When I call other FindyBy methods I get no errors, but the findBy defined above seems to try to flush the entity manager which then results in this violation. I can also duplicate the violation with an entityManager.flush() operation.

Comment: can you put the complete stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. I had my mappings mixed up. The issues is in the stack. Basically, everything works up until a flush is executed as a result on a non CRUD query. When the flush is triggered, it attempts to commit all staged entities. This is where the error is occurring.

Essentially, I have many users with many different groups, the OneToMany mapping creates a table where you can have many users to groups but only one group to a user. Thus there is a unique constraint placed on the groups id on the table itself.

What I wanted, which solved the issue, is to use the ManyToMany mapping.

cheers.